# What is the difference between VSE version and Core version of Vyatta AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I create two instances on AWS, both of them are about Vyatta AMI, one is VSE6.7 version, and the other is Vyatta Core version.

I want to use HA cluster function, if I use the VSE6.7 AMI, I will get the error message, `Configuration path: [cluster] is not valid. Set failed`, by typing "set cluster interface tun00" in configure mode.

But it works on Vyatta Core version.

1. What is the difference between VSE AMI and Core AMI?
2. Should I choose Vyatta Core AMI for cluster function?
3. Is it supported on
   VSE AMI?

   Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cluster feature was deprecated in VSE6.7 which is why you receive the error.

If you want the cluster feature you will have to use the older core release.

If you are interested in other virtualized functions:

The latest incarnation (commercial) from Brocade is the 5600 ( http://www.brocade.com/products/all/network-functions-virtualization/index.page ) and they recently announced a controller, the Brocade Vyatta Controller  ( https://github.com/BRCDcomm/BVC/wiki ).  It is based on the open source OpenDaylight (ODL) controller ( https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Main_Page ).

The OpenDaylight controller allows you to write programs and/or scripts to monitor, configure and control a heterogenous network of virtual (and physical) devices.

SDxCentral maintains a list of virtual switching and routing components:
https://www.sdxcentral.com/comprehensive-list-virtual-switching-routing/